# Angular2 http.post not working

Tags: node.js, angular

Service:

```
postJson() {
    var json = JSON.stringify({
      "key": "CT",
      "values": ["FSP", "HMC", "PHYP","hell"]
    });
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    //let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/add',json,headers)
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Component:

```
postData;
onTestPost() {
     this._httpService.postJson()
          .subscribe(
                data=> this.postData = JSON.stringify(data),
                error=> alert(error),
                () => console.log("finished")
          )
   }
```

Node.js Script

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));
console.log( __dirname);


app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received request'+JSON.stringify(req.body));
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/CTRoot/data.json', JSON.stringify(req.body), (err) => {

    //if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File written to JSON.json');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

//Add as many Headers as you want to line below
//If you use "Authentication" Header, insert it like 'Content-type, Authentication'
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type')
res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    res.send('File written to JSON.json')
  })
});
```

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

I have tried adding many headers, but it's not working.

following output is coming
File written to JSON.json

req.body is coming empty, but in web network request header and body is as expected

Comment: Instead of `.map(res => res.json());` can you try `.map(res => res.text());` or just `.map(res => res);`?

Comment: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data, means the returned data has something in it what shouldn´t be there. Probably a Error message. Look in the retrieved data and post it here. Dont look in the body, look in the network tab response.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `JSON.stringify` to create the request body? that makes the request body type `text` instead of `application/json`.

So try:

```
postJson() {
    let json = {
      "key": "CT",
      "values": ["FSP", "HMC", "PHYP","hell"]
    };

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/add',json,headers)
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I ran a quick test trying to send request body as `text`, where my api expects `application/json`, I get this error back:

`{"code":500,"message":"Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"}`